# SPRESENSE SDK は、Arduino IDE でも使える？

Tags: spresense, arduino

SPRESENSE SDK 利用は、Arduino IDE でも使える的なお話があったように記憶していますが、以前から読んでいた資料でも、できるような印象ありませんが、ほんとはできますでしょうか？

[1.5. シリアルターミナル上での動作確認 (Spresense SDK チュートリアル)](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/set-up-the-nuttx-environment#_%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E7%A2%BA%E8%AA%8D)

Comment: オフトピックとしてこの質問へクローズ票を入れます。なぜならスタックオーバーフローではない、何か別の組織（レクチャー会？）に向けての発言に見受けられます。

Comment: 質問内容そのものは問題ないと思いますが、スタックオーバーフローはSonyと直接関連のないサイトなので、その点を踏まえた投稿文にしてもらうとよいと思います。今のタイトルと文面だと [イベント](https://ai-iot-bol-fukui.connpass.com/event/120312/) でのやり取りをSonyの担当者に直接メールで送っているような印象を与えます。

Comment: SONYのサイトでここに誘導されているので、何か取り決めなどが交わされているのでは？ [Spresense のプログラミングに関する質問を Stack Overflow に投稿するには](https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/support/spresense-programming-support-on-stack-overflow/) SONYのサポート担当者も登録されて回答されていますし、英語版StackOverflowでも、企業がサポート窓口として広報していることもあるようです。

Comment: FWIW https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: 質問者さんの疑問点自体は解決できたようなので、第三者にも役立つQ&Aになるよう、スタック・オーバーフロー向けではない文言をすべて削り、ご質問の本質部分だけになるよう編集してみました。

Answer (score 4):

質問の扱いについて議論中の状況ですが、質問内容は、"**ArduinoIDE から SDK の API にアクセスできるでしょうか？**"ということであっていますか？だとすると答えは"**出来ます**"です。

私の Windows10 の環境の場合、"My Documents\Arduino Data" の中の "SPRESENSE" フォルダにソースコードがあるのですが、その内容を見れば、SPRESENSE の Arduino 用のライブラリが SDK の API をベースに作られていることが分かります。（API の解説が十分ではないので、私はよくそこを眺めています）

試しに以下のようなコードを SDK のサンプルを参考に Arduino IDE 上で作ってコンパイルしたのですが、なんとなく動きました（A0に電圧を印加したら、それらしく値は変化しました）。

ご参考まで。

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>   
#include <arch/chip/cxd56_scu.h>
#include <arch/chip/cxd56_adc.h>

int fd;
int ret;
void setup() {
  fd = open("/dev/lpadc0", O_RDONLY);
  if (fd < 0) {
      printf("open /dev/lpadc0 failed\n");
      return;
  }
  ret = ioctl(fd, SCUIOC_SETFIFOMODE, 1);
  if (ret < 0) {
      printf("ioctl(SETFIFOMODE) failed\n");
      return;
  }
  ret = ioctl(fd, ANIOC_CXD56_START, 0);
  if (ret < 0) {
      printf("ioctl(START) failed\n");
      return;
  }  
}

#define BUFSIZE 16
char buf[BUFSIZE];
void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  ssize_t nbytes = read(fd, buf, BUFSIZE);
  if (nbytes <= 0) {
      printf("read failed or zero\n");
      return;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i+=2) {
    int n = i / 2;
    uint16_t data = buf[i] << 8 | buf[i+1]; // big endian? little endian?
    printf("data[%d]: %d\n",n ,data);
  }
}
```

Comment: その通りです。ホームページからの印象では出来ない印象を受けていました。お忙しいところ情報いただきありがとうございます。試させていただきます。