# Sony SpresenseのBlutooth LE Add-on-ボードについて

Tags: spresense

Bluetooth LE Add-on-ボードを使用してできることを知りたいです。

センサAdd-onボードに対応したセンサではなく、市販のセンサから計測したセンサデータを、BLE通信を用いてRaspberryPiで受信することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　1つの質問に2つの疑問が入っているようですが、2つ目の疑問については別質問にて解決しているように思います :)　[SPRESENSE SDK は、Arduino IDE でも使える？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53466/19110)

Comment: すみません。確認不足でした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「市販のセンサ」が何なのかによってAdd-onボードに接続して使えるかどうかが変わるのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth LE Add-on-ボードの送受信に関するArduinoサンプルソースおよびライブラリが
下記のRohm社GitHubサイトに上がっております。
https://github.com/RohmSemiconductor/Arduino/tree/master/MK71251-02

こちらを参考に、お使いの市販センサのデータ読み出しを行う処理を追加していただき、
そちらのデータをBLEでホスト(RaspberryPiなど）に送信するプログラムを作成されることが
可能かと思います。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。市販のセンサの値を読み出し、Rohm社が指定するiOSのBLE toolでセンサの値を受け取ることは出来ましたが、Add-on-ボードのサービスとキャラクタリスティックのUUIDを見つけることが出来ず、RaspberryPiでは受け取れていないのが現状です。

Answer (score 0):

SPRESENSE の BLEアドオンボードの UUID が分からない件、下記の方法で取得できましたので備忘録を兼ねて共有します。環境は Windows10 です。

【STEP1】Anaconda 等でBLEライブラリ "Bleak" をインストール

```
pip install bleak
```

【STEP2】MACアドレスを取得するための Pythonコードを記述

```
import asyncio
from bleak import discover

async def run():
  devices = await discover()
  for d in devices:
    print(d)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

【STEP3】 SPRESENSE+BLEをリセットし、Pythonコードを実行（MACアドレスが表示されます）

```
(SPRESENSEをリセット)
> python scan.py  
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX: LapisDev <-- MACアドレス
```

【STEP4】Deviceのサービスを取得するための Python コードを記述し保存（ここでは "getservice.py" とします）

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

address = "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"   # MAC Address

async def run(address, loop):
  async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
    x = await client.is_connected()
    print("Connected: {0}".format(x))
    svcs = await client.get_services()
    print("Services:")
    for service in svcs:
      print(service)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run(address, loop))
```

【STEP5】SPRESENSE＋BLEをリセットし、Python コードを実行

```
(SPRESENSEをリセット)
> python getservice.py  
Connected: True
Services:
00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 1): Generic Access Profile
00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 257): Generic Attribute Profile
0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 513): Device Information
0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 769): Battery Service
0179bbd0-5351-48b5-bf6d-2167639bc867 (Handle: 1025): Unknown
```

終了時に時折タイムアウトエラーが出ますが、UUIDは取得できるのでご容赦ください。