# Arduino IDEでPWM出力を15Bitで扱う方法

Tags: spresense

Arduino IDEを使いSpresenseでPWM出力をしたいのですが、IDEではデフォルトが8Bitととなっており、変更ができないようです。(ArduinoDueを除く)
しかしSpresenseでは15Bitの分解能を持っています。

分解能が256と制限されているのは少々扱いづらいので、32768(15Bit)でPWM出力ができるような関数があれば教えてほしいです。

Arduino Due では `analogWriteResolution(bits)` のように書くそうです。

**環境:**
Arduino1.8.12
ボードVer1.5.1
Windows10 Home

Answer (score 1):

残念ながら、ArduinoのCPUのATmega328のPWMカウンタは８ビット幅しかありません。
なので、８ビット以上の分解能をもたせることは不可能となります。

Answer (score 1):

Arduino IDE から直接 nuttx のドライバを叩けば出来るかも知れません。Spresense の PWM のドライバの定義は次にあります。

https://github.com/SPRESENSE/spresense-nuttx/blob/master/include/nuttx/drivers/pwm.h

この中で、pwm のドライバは次のように記述されています。

```
struct pwm_info_s
{
  uint32_t           frequency; /* Frequency of the pulse train */

#ifdef CONFIG_PWM_MULTICHAN
                                /* Per-channel output state */
  struct pwm_chan_s  channels[CONFIG_PWM_NCHANNELS];

#else
  ub16_t             duty;      /* Duty of the pulse train, "1"-to-"0" duration.
                                 * Maximum: 65535/65536 (0x0000ffff)
                                 * Minimum:     1/65536 (0x00000001) */
#  ifdef CONFIG_PWM_PULSECOUNT
  uint32_t           count;     /* The number of pulse to generate.  0 means to
                                 * generate an indefinite number of pulses */
#  endif
#endif /* CONFIG_PWM_MULTICHAN */
};
```

使い方は次のサンプルが参考になると思います。（Spresense SDK をダウンロードすれば examples の中にマージされるみたいです）

https://github.com/jodersky/nuttx/blob/master/apps/examples/pwm/pwm_main.c

ドライバはLinuxと同じように使えます。

```
  pwm_devinit();

  /* Open the PWM device for reading */
  fd = open(g_pwmstate.devpath, O_RDONLY);

  /* Configure the characteristics of the pulse train */
  info.frequency = frequency;
  info.duty      = duty;

  ioctl(fd, PWMIOC_SETCHARACTERISTICS, (unsigned long)((uintptr_t)&info));

  /* Then start the pulse train.  Since the driver was opened in blocking
   * mode, this call will block if the count value is greater than zero.   */
  ioctl(fd, PWMIOC_START, 0);
```

という感じです。Arduino IDEからNuttXのドライバを呼び出し方は過去のスタックオーバーフローで回答していますので、参考にしてください。

[SPRESENSE SDK は、Arduino IDE でも使える？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53466/spresense-sdk-%e3%81%af-arduino-ide-%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b/53502#53502)

中途半端な回答かも知れませんが、ご参考になれば！